# k8s weave and hostNetwork=true giving random ports

Tags: networking, kubernetes, weave

If i spawn a pod with

> hostNetwork: true

and then attach to it

> kubectl exec -it my-pod-test bash

and spawn something silly like

> nc -l < HOST_IP > 5678

and netstat shows me

> tcp 0    0 0.0.0.0:34592    0.0.0.0:*     LISTEN       94/nc

Why is the random port (in this case) 34592 assigned? Id expect to see port 5678 in use.

Is this a "feature" of Weave, should i go for another networking addon?

More context: I am trying to follow 
https://www.compoundtheory.com/scaling-dedicated-game-servers-with-kubernetes-part-1-containerising-and-deploying/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You don't say what image your pod is running, but I've had this symptom when using the [busybox](https://busybox.net/) `nc`, as found in images based on [alpine](https://hub.docker.com/_/alpine/) for instance.

As you will see in [the docs](https://busybox.net/downloads/BusyBox.html#nc), the syntax to listen on a specific port is:

```
  nc -l -p 5678
```

Note that `hostNetwork: true` bypasses any pod network, so this has nothing to do with [Weave Net](https://www.weave.works/oss/net/) - your pod is running in the host network, just as if it was a process run directly on the host.

Comment: yes, thank you, my chaotic debugging copy-paste made me loose the -p flag between the lines!

Comment: It's burned into my mind because I once spent 30 minutes, while teaching a training course, trying to figure out why this exact line wasn't working!